# Ruby: Changing a coordinate in a two-dimensional array without changing all values of a column

Tags: arrays, ruby, debugging, multidimensional-array, deep-copy

I'm befuddled. In [my Ruby code](https://github.com/globewalldesk/battleship_v3/blob/master/lib/fleet.rb#L100), I've got a two-dimensional array of dots, which is assigned to an instance variable in a Battleship game:

```
@dotty_board = 
[[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."]]
```

Now if that's all it was, I could easily type

```
@dotty_board[5][5] = 'C'
print @dotty_board
```

and I'd see something like this, right?

```
[[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "C", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."]]
```

In fact, I typed exactly that in a small Ruby test file. Of course it works that way.

But in the context of my game code, I have a `@dotty_board` variable with precisely the above contents and I've confirmed its class is Array. (If it matters, I create it by a method call on an instance object. But it's not an instance object; it's an array.) I can type precisely the above two lines, and then, instead, I see this:

```
[[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "C", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "C", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "C", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "C", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "C", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "C", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "C", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "C", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "C", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "C", ".", ".", ".", "."]]
```

The sixth element of every row is now a 'C', not just of the sixth row. In other words, after I change the value of 5,5 to 'C', the value of 0,5 through 9,5 also changes to 'C'. I tried a lot of testing and research, and I can't figure it out. I just know I'm going to slap my forehead very audibly when someone reveals the secret. What the holy $#!+ could be going on? Any ideas?

---

I've confirmed that the problem has something to do with my `@dotty_board` variable. I exactly copied my test code within the document itself, code that has the weird effect with `@dotty_board`. I then `@dotty_board` to `@ditty_board` and assigned this new variable to the two-dimensional array of dots you see above. Well, `ditty_board[5][5] = 'C'` works exactly as expected in that context, it changes only that one coordinate.

But what on earth could there be about `@dotty_board` (an Array class object) that could make it have this different behavior?

---

The answer is given below. It seems that the way my array was initialized was not right for an array whose values might need to be updated.

---

A friend of mine heard my summary of the problem and solution, and nodded sagely, saying, "Ah. [Deep vs. shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)."

Comment: You have a problem that has come up many times on SO. You need define the array as follows: `@dotty_board = Array.new(10) { Array.new(10) { "." } }`. Then `@dotty_board[1][2] = "C"` changes only that one element.

Comment: Yep, you guys are right. That fixed it.